# Is there a grammatical difference between "heart of oak" and "hearts of oak" in the British patriotic song "Heart of Oak?"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, word-usage, construction

A British patriotic song titled "Heart of Oak" has two versions that are widely sung.

The chorus in the first version goes like this:

```
Heart of oak are our ships,
Heart of oak are our men,
We always are ready, steady boys, steady,
To charge and to conquer again and again.
```

The chorus in the second version reads as follows:

```
Hearts of oak are our ships,
Hearts of oak are our men,
We always are ready, steady boys, steady,
To charge and to conquer again and again.
```

Is there any grammatical difference between using "*heart* of oak" versus "*hearts* of oak" in the song? Are both versions grammatically correct?

In addition, is it grammatically correct to use this construction in other contexts? Can I use "heart of aluminum is my car" for "my car is made of aluminum?"

I recently read the lyrics of this song online and I have never seen this grammatical construction used before, so I am wondering about the grammatical aspects of it.

Comment: @WeatherVane, if it is a poetic inversion, then why does it use “hearts of oak ARE our ships” rather than “hearts of oak HAVE our ships?” The only other construction that I could think of is “our ships have hearts of oak.” In addition, would using such language to describe my car be appropriate in poetry or song?

Comment: It's a pun meaning both "made from the heart of the oak tree" and "having hearts (i.e. the seat of the passions) made of oak"; the latter uses oak as a symbol for Englishness. "Our hearts are English" means we are English in some deep way, and "heart of oak" means the same if oak=English.

Comment: The poetic inversion and deletion from 'Our ships are made [partly] from _heart of oak_' makes for good lyrics but uncomfortable grammar and accuracy, especially when twinned with the metaphor of the second line (and yes, why 'are' not 'have' here?) Probably some have made an attempt to improve things, probably unwisely.  But as @Weather Vane says, lyrics do not need to be grammatical. So the question is not suitable for ELU (this is often true for questions about lyrics, which often abandon standard usages).

Comment: @WeatherVane, are there any instances when you could use "heart of X is Y" to mean "Y is made of X?"

Comment: Do you mean "The heart of my vehicle is aluminium"? More usually that would be "My vehicle has a heart of aluminium" but it lacks the punch and the play on ideas seen in ships and sailors having hearts of oak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song involves countable and uncountable noun phrases and a pun:

"Heart of oak" is an uncountable noun phrase in which "heart" = "heartwood" and describes the literal construction of the ship.

OED

> **Heartwood**:  **2. The dense, inner part of the wood of a tree trunk, yielding the hardest timber, often darker in colour and more resistant to decay than the surrounding wood due to higher gum or resin content.**
>
> **Oak** is a material noun and also uncountable ("The chair is oak" cf "The chains are steel.")

In "Hearts of Oak" "**Hearts**" is countable and refers to a respected person:

OED

> **22.** *Originally:* **a person considered in respect of his or her bravery, courage, or other admirable qualities (usually with preceding modifying adjective). In later (esp. Nautical) use also in plural [...], esp. as my hearts (now archaic; cf. hearty n. 2).**
>
> 1626   J. Smith Accidence Young Sea-men 25 *Courage my hearts for a fresh charge.*
>
> 1834   T. Hood Storm iv, in Comic Ann. 103 *Come, my hearts, be stout and bold.*
>
> 1988   Cincinnati Mag. Mar. 81/1 *Those stout hearts who are paid to predict the Bulls and Bears of a market gone berserk.*

In Hearts of oak - the Oak is a reference to England/Englishmen. The oak tree (through its association with strength and nobility - and also the navy) is the generally accepted (jingoistic) metaphor for the quality of an Englishman.

Thus
**Heart of oak are our ships,** = our ships are of the strongest wood

**Heart of oak are our men,** = our men are as strong as the strongest wood.

**Hearts of oak are our ships,** = our ships are greatly respected

**Hearts of oak are our men,** = our men are our dear and courageous friends

Comment: So wouldn't 'Heart of oak are our ships,
Hearts of oak are our men ...' be more felicitous?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I did some research and it turns out that there is a version that uses “Heart of oak are our ships, Hearts of oak are our men.”

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Oak states that 'heart of oak' is the wood from which ships were constructed at the time the song was written (1759). It is the wood from the centre of an oak tree and this is the strongest part of the tree. It's understandable that, over the years, some versions should have evolved into 'hearts' as the reference is to multiple ships and men. You would have to ask David Garrick why he used *are* rather than *have!*

The song is probably *played* much more often than it is *sung*, as the official march of the Royal Navy. If you used a similar phrase to describe your car, probably the only people to 'get' it would be history buffs familiar with the words.